# How to create arrow in div from both side?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a div structure like this but I am unable to do that, Can someone help me?

I am created something like this?

[image]

How to Create this type of design. I am able to code only sigle side arrow.

```css
.right-arrow {
    position: relative;
    padding: 15px;
}
.right-arrow:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -10px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
}
.hiring-process1 .hiring-process .custom-process{
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    margin: 25px;
}
.hiring-process1 .hiring-process .process1{
    background: #10145b;
}
.hiring-process1 .hiring-process .process1:after{
    border-left: 10px solid #10145b;
}
.hiring-process1 .hiring-process .process2{
    background: #1d2570;
    padding: 15px 15px 40px;
}
.hiring-process1 .hiring-process .process2:after{
    border-left: 10px solid #1d2570;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="process1 custom-process right-arrow">
            <p class="number">01</p>
            <p class="text">Identify the <br>hiring need</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
        <div class="process2 custom-process right-arrow">
            <p class="number">02</p>
            <p class="text">Write a JD</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Design :

[image]

After Adding z-index :

[image]

Comment: you need to set the z-index so that the first arrows show up on top.

Comment: When I set z-index : 2 then it will come on top but not create a connecting arrow mark as you can see in the first picture

Comment: If I set the Border color to white, Then It will set the arrow to white color

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `z-index: 2;` and `border-right: 10px solid white;` for the `right-arrow` class.

[z-index](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) places elements in front of or behind other elements.

[border](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border.asp) adds a border to an element.

Comment: Still not fixed

Comment: what's the issue? can you share a picture please?

Answer (score -1):

Setting the zed index to a value higher than 2 should fix this issue.

Comment: z* index, it was a mistake

Comment: When I set z-index : 2 then it will come on top but not create a connecting arrow mark as you can see in the first picture

Comment: sorry for the late reply, like the person above said, setting a border: 1px solid while should fix it